# Visual Studio: structures: error C2440

Tags: c, debugging, structure

Please, I'm asking for help with this,I'm already desperate.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>



typedef struct {
   int citatel, jmenovatel;
} Zlomek;

typedef struct {
    Zlomek j, c;
} Slozeny;


int main()
{
      Zlomek z1 = {2, 5}, z2 = {3, 7};
      Slozeny slozenec = {z1, z2};

      system("PAUSE");
      return 0;
 }
```

When I'm compiling, VS just throws out: error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'Zlomek' to 'int'. Shall someone help me?

Comment: Which version of VS? I made a console win32 app in VS2010 (ultimate) and dropped your code into the auto-generated .cpp file. It compiled without a whimper after I changed `int main()` to `int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])`

Answer (score 0):

You have an old compiler that cannot perform initialisation with non constants.

Use a newer compiler or replace

```
  Slozeny slozenec = {z1, z2};
```

by

```
  Slozeny slozenec ;
  slozenec.j = z1 ;
  slozenec.c = z2 ;
```